# Find missing values of column 1, then add those values and assign column 2 as 0

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with the following data:

```
21599.94          -13006.00                 
21599.95          -13008.00              
21599.96          -13016.00               
21599.97          -13001.00            
21599.98          -13015.00         
21599.99          -13021.00            
25200.00          -13285.00             
25200.01          -13295.00            
25200.02          -13275.00                
25200.03          -13262.00                 
25200.04          -13278.00            
25200.05          -13277.00
```

The data from `21600.00` to `25199.99` (of column 1) are missing. I need a code such that it identifies which all values of column 1 are missing (Please note that the sampling rate is 0.01), then add those values into the file and assign corresponding value for column 2 as 0.

Desired output:

```
21600.00         0           
21600.01         0           
21600.02         0            
21600.03         0              
...             
....              
.....               
25199.98         0          
25199.99         0              
25200.00         -13285.00
```

Comment: ReshmiDas have you tried anything yourself yet? If so, please add your code and its current output to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't usually offer code answers when there's been no obvious attempt. However, today it's sunny and here's my suggestion,

```
awk '
    {
        this = int($1*100 + .5)                 # Counter is integer
    }

    NR == 1 {
        current = this                          # Starting value
    }

    {
        while(current < this) {
            printf "%.2f\t0\n", current/100;    # Output the missing entry
            current++                           # Next increment
        }

        print;                                  # Output current line
        current++                               # Keep in step with expected
    }
' datafile
```

You can crunch it into a single line if you must, but it's more readable this way.